# What can an attacker know with knowledge of a device's BD_ADDR?

Tags: network, wireless, mac-address, bluetooth

Lots of articles mention the importance of keeping the BD_ADDR secret as knowing it can allow an attacker to do stuff. What can an attacker really do?(Assuming that he has knowledge of the UAP + LAP but not NAP which is irrelevant) The most I can think of is that the attacker can attempt to connect to that device even when it is not in discoverable mode but the victim can simply decline the pairing and nothing happens right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It varies by device but in a nutshell with the BD_ADDR attackers can now make use of knowing the devices hopping pattern allowing extracting of data to be possible.

The attacker can then force a rekey of the Secret Link key by impersonating a device that was paired with the target allowing them now to be paired.

The piece where you say decline pairing would not necessarily happen as the device may well believe the impersonating device is indeed on the known device list and not see it as being attacked.